# Python nomarlization

Tags: python-3.x, math

I have some float numbers like:

```
586.3212341231,-847.3829941845
```

I want to use sigmoid function to make the floats in a range of `[1,-1]` for example :

```
0.842931342,-0.481238571
```

Any thoughts about it?
I tried `scipy` but it gives me wrong outcomes.

Comment: `scipy` is not a sigmoid function.

Answer (score 3):

There are many such functions: see [this Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#Examples) for examples. The graphic there in particular gives examples resulting in your desired range, though the endpoints 1 and -1 are not obtainable for finite values of the parameter x.

The simplest function there is

```
x / (1 + abs(x))
```

If you really want your first two sample float numbers to be mapped to your second two float numbers, you can tune your function to be

```
(a + x) / (b + abs(x))
```

for particular values of `a` and `b`. For two desired values of `x` and `f(x)` you can find `a` and `b` by solving two simultaneous linear equations. I used sympy to get the following for your sample values:

```
a = 246.362120860444
b = 401.521207478205
```

So your final resulting function is

```
(246.362120860444 + x) / (401.521207478205 + abs(x))
```

I tested this and it gives just the values you want. Here are two plots showing that this gives your desired range (-1, 1). The first one shows your two points best.

[image]

[image]